# Broken tubes underneath 2000 Dodge Ram 1500

Tags: dodge, wiring, 4wd, ram

*2000 Dodge Ram 1500, Laramie V8 - 5.2L*

While trying to figure out why the 4WD light flickers on and off (when in 2H, it is off while stopped, will come on or flicker after 15-20mph, may randomly go off at 60mph) I was looking under at the front axle and I noticed there is a red/black tube pair.

[image]

**When I followed it up (just a foot) I noticed the red tube was broken**. When I pulled the protective sleeve down to see the red tube , the red inside the protective sleeve snapped off.

[image]

**So my question is, what is the importance of this red tube, and could it be related to my 4WD indicator light issue?**

**Update**

After closer inspection both the black and red tubes had broken apart. I managed to patch them using some thermal tubing, but I suspect that won't actually hold any pressure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you have enough information here to go on. My best advice to you is, fix the wire and see if it fixes the problem. The wire needs to be fixed anyway, so fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Upon closer inspection I discovered it wasn't a wire, but a set of tubes. Some kind of air pressure system? I don't know.

Comment: Since your truck is a 4wd, this may be the port for the breather in the axle. They put a tube on it, which goes up and away from the front axle so you can ford a little deeper water without the worry of getting water into the axle itself. It's good to have in place.